# How to build source to image(S2I) in OpenShift but using the directory under .git repo?

Tags: git, spring-boot, image, openshift, redhat

As the question mentioned,
I want to build source to image (S2I) from git repo, but I want to build the diretory under git repository.

For example, I have a git repository name Test(https://example.com/test.git) and I want to build the project projectA under repository Test (such as https://example.com/test/projectA/), how can I set the build command?

The picture of Test repository(there are 3 project under Test.git)

--git repo:Test

-----project A

-----project B

-----project C

Because I search all the internet, I can only see how to build from git repository like below:

```
oc new-build registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-11~https://github.com/monodot/simple-camel-spring-boot-app \
--name=my-demo-app
```

But there are no example for S2I from the project/directory under repository.

Comment: Please do not use existing domains as examples. I changed it to `example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-code) say you can set repository URI, ref (branch/tag/commit ID) and `contextDir`. Form the docs: *The contextDir field allows you to override the default location inside the source code repository where the build looks for the application source code. If your application exists inside a sub-directory, you can override the default location (the root folder) using this field.*

[Man page for `oc new-build`](https://www.mankier.com/1/oc-new-build) says the command line option is [`--context-dir`](https://www.mankier.com/1/oc-new-build#--context-dir).

So in your example the command is

```
oc new-build https://example.com/test.git --context-dir=projectA
```